# Pascal ABC. Встречено '=', а ожидалось ';'

Tags: pascalabc.net

```
program PR3;
const a=1.5; p=3.14;
var a,x,y: real;
begin
  writeln('Введите x: ');
  read(x);
    if x<1.3 then
    begin
     y=p*sqr(x)-7/sqr(x); {Здесь ошибка}
     writeln('y= ', y);
      if x=1.3 then 
      begin
       y=a*exp(ln(X)*3)+7sqrt(x); {здесь так же пишет ошибку}
       writeln('y= ');
        if x>1.3 then 
        begin
         y=log(x+7*sqrt(x); {здесь так же если убрать предыдущие}
         writeln('y= ');
      end;
    end;
  end;
end.
```

Выдаёт ошибку Встречено '=', а ожидалось ';' при каждом "="

Comment: А это у вас паскаль. Насколько я помню синтаксис паскаля, оператор присвоения выглядит как ':=',  а не '='. Обратите внимание на формулы, они у вас с ошибками. Во второй потеряли знак в 7sqrt, в третьей не хватает закрывающей скобки.

Comment: Спасибо, насчёт ":=" забыл и в примере, с которого дали писать, было без точек. А до того, пробовал убрать равно и писало, что Встречено "*", а ожидалось ";". И при выполнении программа выполняет только первую часть. Вторую и третью развилку она будто не видит.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if SameValue(x, 1.3) then 
begin
  ...
end
else if x < 1.3 then
begin
  y := p * sqr(x) - 7 / sqr(x);
  writeln('y= ', y);
end
else if x > 1.3 then
begin
  ...
end;
```